# is there a way to have a div with box-shadow inset and normal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and I want it to have a box-shadow inset and just normal.

I tried giving it 2 box-shadows `1 inset and 1 normal` but it did not work.
I also tried to google it but I could not find what I want.

This is my current code.

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  <head>
  <body>
    <div>hello world</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is only giving the last `box-shadow` is there a way to give the first `box-shadow` to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `box-shadow` value when you add it again.

Instead, use a comma to separate multiple box shadows, like so:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px, 0 0 10px;
```